# Are local martingales semimartingales in an enlarged filtration (under particular assumption)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, filtrations

I'm studying filtration enlargements and I bumped into the following problem.

Assume there are two filtrations $\mathbb{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \in T}$ and $\mathbb{H}=(\mathcal{H}_t)_{t \in T}$ on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ such that, for all $t \in T$,

$$
\mathcal{F}_t \subset \mathcal{H}_t
$$

Consider the following statements:
$$
(A) \qquad \mbox{every }\mathbb{F}-\mbox{martingale is a }\mathbb{H}-\mbox{semimartingale} 
$$

$$
(B) \qquad \mbox{every }\mathbb{F}-\mbox{local martingale is a }\mathbb{H}-\mbox{semimartingale} 
$$

Is it true that (A) implies (B)?

*Some context:*

I'm asking because I found that in literature both these conditions are known as hypothesis $H'$, in the sense that it's possible to find under the same name both the conditions

1. Every $\mathbb{F}-$martingale is a $\mathbb{H}-$semimartingale
2. Every $\mathbb{F}-$semimartingale is a $\mathbb{H}-$semimartingale

My gut guess is that 1 implies 2. To prove it, I noticed that it's enough to show that (A) implies (B) (as any $\mathbb{F}$-adapted process $F$ with finite variation is also a $\mathbb{H}$-adapted process with finite variation and the sum of a $\mathbb{H}-$semimartingale and $F$ it's again an $\mathbb{H}-$semimartingale).

Comment: obviously B (and 2) implies A as every martingale is a trivial local martingale (semimartingale). I doubt that the other way is true but have no proof at the moment